# Laravel 5 Model $cats to array utf-8 JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When you have an array field and save it in the DB it does a nifty json_encode to the array but without the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option. The data end up like so :

`{"en":"\u039d\u03ad\u03b1"}`

which is pretty much useless. The solution of course is to json_encode with the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag.
 Is it possible to tell Laravel to add this option before saving the model?

I am trying to avoid using the setNameAttribute mutator as this would be kind of a pain to do it every time i have this type of fields

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just override the `asJson()` method.

```
class Cat extends Model
{

    // ...

    protected function asJson($value)
    {
        return json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

}
```

If you don't want to repeat the method for all your models, just extract the method to an abstract class:

```
abstract class UnicodeModel extends Model 
{
    protected function asJson($value)
    {
        return json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

Now you inherit from `UnicodeModel` instead of `Model`:

```
class Cat extends UnicodeModel 
{
    // ...
}
```

---

In case you need a finer casting control you can override the `setAttribute` method, e.g.:

```
class Cat extends Model
{

    // ...

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {

        // take special care for the attributes foo, bar and baz
        if (in_array($key, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])) {
            $this->attributes[$key] = json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

            return $this;
        }

        // apply default for everything else
        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment i am using the setAttribute mutator. Thing is, i was looking for a more "automatic" solution to avoid having these methods in all of my models (multilingual models, saving a json in the db field)

Comment: Had one more idea for a cleaner solution. Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, this is not a bad idea. Cheers for that

Comment: Very nice. I like the abstract class approach.

Answer (score 3):

Better for **Laravel's Model**:

```
$yourModel->toJson(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```